# Default value of virtual property

Tags: c#

So I have abstract class with following absract class:

```
public abstract class BankAccount
{
    public virtual double InterestRate { get; protected set; } = 2.35;

    public virtual double CalculateInterest(int months)
    {
        return months * this.InterestRate;
    }
}
```

then I have derived class:

```
public class LoanAccount : BankAccount
{
    public override double CalculateInterest(int months)
    {
        if ((this.Customer is Individual && months <= 3) || (this.Customer is Company && months <= 2))
        {
            this.InterestRate = 1.00;
        }
        return base.CalculateInterest(months);
    }
}
```

here is the invocation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new List<BankAccount>(10)
    {
        new LoanAccount(new Individual(), 1000)
    };

    Console.WriteLine(bankAccounts[0].CalculateInterest(4));
}
```

> When I call `loanAccount.CalculateInterest(4)` when I enter
>   `base.CalculateInterest` method all it gives me for `InterestRate` is
>   `0`. Why? doesn't it have to be 2.35 since this property has a default value?

Comment: It does, if you call `new LoanAccount().CalculateInterest(...)`. I can't reproduce what you're seeing. Check if `InterestRate` isn't set somewhere else before it hits your code (which seems possible, since, after all, the `CalculateInterest` method shown here also modifies the field). From a design perspective, such protected fields are a bad idea precisely because of what you're seeing now. If the calculation varies per class, why do they need a shared `InterestRate` field? Who could meaningfully use it?

Comment: Where are you seeing that `InterestRate` is 0? Plus I echo @JeroenMostert's question as to why the property is virtual in the first place?  Do you intend to override the getter and/or setter at some point?

Comment: @ D Stanley I am seeing InterestRate = 0 when I am debugging and I pause at base `CalculateInterest` method when I invoke the method like follows `Console.WriteLine(bankAccounts[0].CalculateInterest(4));` where `bankAccounts` is `List<BankAccounts>` and `bankAccounts[0] is LoanAccount`

Comment: This code doesn't compile as posted. If you want a full analysis you'll need to include a [mcve]. Creating such an example may also help you narrow down where the problem is in the first place.

Comment: I answered my question if you are curious you can check it, thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to answer my question , the problem was that property in `BankAccount` is `virtual` and then overriden in `LoanAccount` therefore when I invoke `CalculateInterest` it is using the overriden property in derived class(`LoanAccount`) rather than virtual one(in `BankAccount`) which leads me to think that I should be really really careful using virtual properties.